# Cannot receive data from server using socket.recv()

Tags: java, python, sockets, networking, network-programming

I have a python client which send some data(namespace, metric_name, timestamp, metric_value, dimensions) in json format to a java server and receive the responce.

Here is part of the client side code:

```
def _init_socket(self):
    logger.info("initial socket, hostname {}, port {}".format(self.host, self.port))
    client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    address = (self.host, self.port)
    client.connect(address)
    self.client = client

def send_put_metrics_request(self, namespace, metric_name, metric_value, dimensions): 
    try:
        self._init_socket()
        timestamp = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
        send_data = self.convert_to_json(namespace, metric_name, timestamp, metric_value, dimensions)
        self.client.send(bytes(send_data + "\n", encoding=self.encoding))
        self.client.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)

        data = self.client.recv(1024)
        print(data)

    finally:
        self.client.close()
```

At server side, I just want to return HelloWorld to client. Here is part of the java server code:

```
    public void start() {
        logger.info("Daemon Server is listening for metrics");

        try (final ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket()) {
            final int port = 7072;
            serverSocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(port));

            while (true) {
                final Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                threadPool.submit(() -> process(socket));
            }
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            logger.error(Thread.currentThread().getId() + " failed to make a connection to the server socket"
                + e.getMessage());
            throw new ConnectToServerSocketException(Thread.currentThread().getId()
                + " failed to make a connection to the server socket" + e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            threadPool.shutdown();
        }
    }


    protected void process(final Socket socket) {
        final Message message;
        try (final InputStream input = socket.getInputStream()) {
            final OutputStream output = socket.getOutputStream();
            final OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(output, "UTF8");
            final PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(osw));
            message = objectMapper.readValue(inputStreamToString(input), Message.class);
// pls ignore the below line, it just calls another method to do something
            final String res = forwardMetrics(message);
            logger.info("Thread " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " processed result: " + res);

            writer.println("HelloWorld"+"\n");
            writer.flush();
            socket.close();
            logger.info("Socket closed")

        } catch (final IOException e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
            logger.error("Daemon server failed to read input from socket");
            throw new ReadFromSocketException("Failed to read input from socket", e);
        }

    }
```

Then after I started the server and sent the request in right format through client. I didn't get 'HelloWorld' from client side. The print result is just **b' '**. From the log at server side, it executed all the lines until the socket was closed.

I was wondering why there isn't anything printed out.

Answer (score 0):

It is not guaranteed that `socket.recv()` in client will return response on first fetch. I suggest you to call `recv()` in a while loop until it receives `None`.

Comment: Hi thanks for the information. I have tried to add loop for this. Unfortunately it doesn't work. It keeps getting 0 byte but not any data here.

Comment: Okay. I just tested above code in the same form, and it is working for me.!